# Can IIS7+ configured to retain the type of http-method during redirecting to different url

Tags: iis, asp-classic

is there anyone expert enough in IIS7+ server and also web.config settings to say if it is possible to configure IIS server retain http-method (verb) while redirecting to different url - in the case of page-not-found-error 404 with the typical httpErrors dealing via web.config?

```
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>  
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/restApp/config/restMappings.asp" 
     responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      <error statusCode="403" path="/restApp/config/restMappings.asp" 
      responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
     enter code here</httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
```

Problem is that redirecting this way usually changes the http-method to GET-method irrespective of original request method, like POST or DELETE. So, in server variables you always only have GET after redirection. Is is possible somehow to retain the original http-method after redirection, so that it is available in the corresponding server-variable?

I am neeeding this in classic asp scenario for restful apis.

Comment: A server sid redirect by definition is a `GET` request in Classic ASP. But it is possible in HTTP, what you are looking for is a [`307 Temporary Redirect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307) see [Why doesn't HTTP have POST redirect?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/99894/131815).

Comment: If you are using the redirect within the same web application, you could use `Server.Transfer()` to silently call another page without the URL being changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirecting postdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178183/redirecting-postdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTTP code [`307 Temporary Redirect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307) to maintain the HTTP method during redirection.

```
Response.Status = "307 Temporary Redirect"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.example.com/"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! - this made indeed possible to retain original http-methods after redirecting. Now I can perform ajax-request with possibility to catch the http-methods according to type and to continue with restful apis.